# CodeIgniter defaulting views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've got this controller called Page

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Page extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index($page = 'home')
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
                // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view($page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

but currently it only loads the home.php page by going to http://www.example.com/

I'm trying to make it so if I go to example.com/test it would load test.php

Here are my routes

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'page';
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/$1';
```

I am new to php frameworks, and I'm not sure how to achieve this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter routing works in a way that it would point `example.com/test` to a the index function of a controller called `Test.php` in your controllers folder.

The following is the conventions for codeigniter url routing:

```
http://www.example.com/controller/function_in_that_controller/parameters/in/that/function
```

At `http://www.example.com/controller/`, the index function is called by default; since no function is defined in the url after the controller.

Comment: Okay, so how do I make the test page load through the index function of my page controller? I tried `example.com/page/index/test` and `example.com/index/test` and `example.com/page/test` and nothing seems to be working

Comment: try example.com/index.php/test , if that works, look into getting the .htaccess file from the codeigniter documentation to be able to access the page at http://www.example.com/test

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/$1';
```

To

```
$route['(:any)'] = 'page/index/$1';
```

Comment: I did that, now how do I access the page? I tried `http://www.example.com/test` with no dice.

Comment: Hopefully, you have `test.php` file in views directory. First test it over `http://www.example.com/index.php/test`. If that works, than check `.htaccess` file setting and `config.php` file setting.